# cannot unset env variables from script

Tags: bash, scripting, environment-variables, source

I am trying to unset all environment variables from within a script. The script runs fine but if I run env it still shows all the variables set.
If I run the command from CLI, it works and the variables are unset.

```
unset `env | awk -F= '/^\w/ {print $1}' | xargs`
```

Have any idea how to run this from a script?
Also, have any idea how to source /etc/profile from a script? This doesn't work either.

I need to set variables with same names but different paths, depending on the instances my users need.

Later edit:
ok, I ended up with this (rather not elegant, but whatever) solution:

```
. script
```

which contains:

```
unset `env | awk -F= '/^\w/ {print $1}'|egrep -v "HOSTNAME|TERM|SHELL|HISTSIZE|SSH_CLIENT|SSH_TTY|USER|LS_COLORS|KDEDIR|MAIL|PATH|INPUTRC|PWD|LANG|HISTIGNORE|SSH_ASKPASS|TEST|SHLVL|HOME|LD_ASSUME_KERNEL|LOGNAME|SSH_CONNECTION|LESSOPEN|HISTTIMEFORMAT|G_BROKEN_FILENAMES|_"|xargs`
source env_variable_file
```

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a standard answer, basically. You can't do that, because the script runs in a new child process. That process gets its own environment, and can't change that of the parent, either to set variables or to unset them.

You can run the script in the current environment using the `.` command. And you can source /etc/profile in the same way:

> . /etc/profile

Comment: If you *source* the child script, yes. We are saying the same thing.

Comment: this one actually worked, ". script"

Answer (score 3):

I tried to run your script and it does not work for me.

I google a bit and found this:

```
unset $(/usr/bin/env | egrep '^(\w+)=(.*)$' | \
egrep -vw 'PWD|USER|LANG' | /usr/bin/cut -d= -f1);
```

This one actually works ;-)

For sourcing files

```
source /etc/profile
```

is the right way as you said.

If I modify your script like this

```
unset $(env | awk -F= '{print $1}' | xargs)
```

it also works.

I do not think if there is any difference running the command interactively vs from a script.

Comment: his unset 'env/awk' method worked just fine for me. bash 4.1.7.

Comment: may be an OS thing, RHE 4, bash 3.00.15.

Answer (score 0):

Use -v to the unset command to rip items out of the environment; note at the end of this test script how you may get errors because we've unset $PATH so it can't find programs like 'id' and such.

```
#!/bin/sh

LIST=`env | awk -F= '/^\w/ {print $1}' | xargs`

for item in $LIST; do
  echo "$item = ${!item}";
done

unset -v $LIST

for item in $LIST; do
  echo "$item = ${!item}";
done

HISTSIZE=5555
echo $HISTSIZE
source /etc/profile
echo $HISTSIZE
```

Comment: well, I can't do it like this because I must assume that $LIST already contains variables set up manually by the user, and I need to drop them in order the set up same ones with different values. But yes, I ended up using -v, as you also suggested.